# How can I convert my dryer to plug in in my apartment

Tags: wiring

There are no hook ups in my apartment there is an air conditioning unit though. Is there away to connect my dryer there

Comment: Does your apartment have laundry hookups of any sort? What does the nameplate on your dryer say it requires?  Or does your building/complex have a central laundry facility instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the building wiring without your landlord's permission, *period*.  And you won't get it.  Most places it's *not even* his permission to give, as by local ordinance, work on rental units must be done by licensed electricians.  If he is willing to give permission, and you are willing to front the cost of the electrician, then you might as well do it right and install a proper NEMA 14-30 receptacle and dryer vent. Do not install a 10-30 simply because your dryer has that cord: change cord to a 14-30.

That said, it's possible, not easy, to hack a dryer to run on 120V only.  The secret is that a 240V heating element will also work on 120V at half the amps and 1/4 the power.  This puts it within reach of a common 120V/15A receptacle.  It will dry clothes *rather slowly* and more by blowing dry air around than actual heat... So you'll need the dryer exhaust to be absolutely tip-top.  If the dryer is discharging into the dryer room, it will be ingesting its own 100% humidity air, and won't dry at all.